# Using 2 LiPo 18650 with L7805CV, is 7.2V enough to run the device?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator

I am interested in powering a robot using two LiPo 18650 batteries, in addition they need to be fed through a regulator to produce a 5V output for a microcontroller.

The problem is the regulator has a dropout voltage of 2V - am I cutting it too close?

Looking at the discharge cycle of the battery it appears it maintains a greater than 3.6V up until close to complete discharge meaning that at least 7.2V will be fed into the regulator.

Is this enough to keep it running?

I could add another battery but that is going above the ideal voltage range for the motors(though with PWM, I believe I can make them not overwork).

Comment: The answer is that it depends on what you want & what the robot will be doing. A dropout at 7.0V means your 18650s will be about 70-80% discharged, so you're getting most of the charge cycle out of them, and could consider it a "bonus battery protection" circuit. If this is acceptable, great...but if that's not enough battery life for you, then another solution is needed. You haven't given us enough criteria to make that decision for you, so we can't help much more than that.

Comment: There is no reason you should use a 7805, use a modern LDO or (better) a SMPS. If the datasheet says 2V, and you give it 2V, it will work.